# How do I automatically enter sequential numbers without using the mouse in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, keyboard-shortcuts, google-sheets-arrayformula

I would like to create a series of number in Google Sheets, without dragging with the mouse.

When using the Shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Fill Right) it just copies the value of the first cell.

**Initial State:**
[image]

**Desired State (achieved by dragging the initial selection via mouse):**
[image]

**Outcome using Cmd-R:**
[image]

Any ideas on how to achieve this without using the mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- another way would be using formula with keyboard shortcuts:
- type in **`=COLUMN(A1)`** in the first cell
- press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>C</kbd>**
- press **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>RIGHT ARROW</kbd>** to select range
- press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>V</kbd>** or press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**

Comment: easiest way to do when mouse is so far away from right hand :D

Answer (score 0):

- you can generate it with formula:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&8))))
  ```

  [image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it to preserve original position number copy values that you get from applying formula and paste only values without formulas with **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>** + **<kbd>Shift</kbd>** + **<kbd>V</kbd>**